# Excel VBA: How to show blanks as 0 in pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro which creates a pivot table with counts. I noticed that in case the count is zero, it is displayed as blank. Is there a way to make it 0 programmatically instead?

Here is my code:

```
With Worksheets("Working")

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & rngData.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & rngData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        TableName:="HDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
End With

ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").AddFields RowFields:="Row Label"

ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotFields("h,d,x").Orientation = xlDataField

With ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotFields("h,d,x")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh

    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        ' Filter out columns that are not "D" or "H"
        If .PivotItems(i) <> "D" And .PivotItems(i) <> "H" Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`PivotTable.NullString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.nullstring):

```
ws.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").NullString = "0"
```